# fieldInfo.SetValue throwing ArgumentException "Object type cannot be converted to target type"

Tags: .net, reflection

This is driving me nuts.  Perhaps I'm missing something obvious?

The fieldInfo.FieldType is correct (DateTime), and the value I'm applying is also a DateTime.

```
for(int i=0; i<objectArray.Length; i++)
{
    FieldInfo destinationField = GetFieldInfo(i);
    object destinationValue = objectArray[i];

    destinationField.SetValue(this, destinationValue);
}
```

Edit: even if I set destinationValue to a literal DateTime (DateTime.Now), I still get the exception!

Comment: Could you post a bit of the offending code?

Comment: Your code can't compile, because GetFieldInfo([i]) is not valid C#. Can you show the real code, and maybe add the following line before the SetValue() call: Console.WriteLine(destinationField.FieldType + "," + destinationValue.GetType())

Comment: @activa.. thanks for responding.  I think it's better to post a simplified version.  Your Console.WriteLine would return System.DateTime,object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out.

If you ever see this Exception, there's a good chance the the FieldInfos you are using do not belong to the same object as your target.  **cough**

Sorry for being a clot, thanks to all who helped out.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to set a property on your object and not a field (this might be your problem). If so then the following code might help?

```
public class Order
{
    public DateTime OrderDateField;
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
}

object[] orders = new[] { new Order(), new Order(), new Order() };
for (int i = 0; i < orders.Length; i++)
{
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = orders[i].GetType().GetField("OrderDateField");
    fieldInfo.SetValue(orders[i], DateTime.Now);

    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = orders[i].GetType().GetProperty("OrderDate");
    propertyInfo.SetValue(orders[i], DateTime.Now, null);
}
```

Is that the result you were trying to achieve?

Update: The above code updates both the property and field on the Order object.

Comment: Thanks, but it is a field and not a property

Comment: It is, but even if it weren't I should be able to set it with a valid FieldInfo reference

Comment: Thanks, I was doing something like this but I tried the literal DateTime.Now value and it still threw the error.  Perhaps my object reference (this) is the problem?

Comment: It might be... perhaps you can not use reflection to set a field on the same object calling the SetValue() method? Sounds plausable?

Comment: Plausble I suppose... if unlikely?

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
destinationField.SetValue(this, destinationValue);
```

To

```
destinationField.SetValue(objectArray[i], destinationValue);
```

There was a comment asking about the 'this' reference, but I lack the rep to reply there.

Comment: this doesn't make any sense... destinationValue is equal to objectArray[i]